# Execute Crontab of the local web request on OSX

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I need to execute a cronjob every 10 minutes for a local web request (i.e. "http://localhost:8888/MyProject/quickstart/public/mycontroller").

I have used Zend Framework(PHP) to create the web project. Any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `crontab` entry ( http://benr75.com/pages/using_crontab_mac_os_x_unix_linux ) and use `curl` ( http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#MacOSX ) to run something like:

`curl http://localhost:8888/MyProject/quickstart/public/mycontroller`

Comment: thanks Nadh. A question, when I put my entry into my crontab list, should it run automatically?

Comment: @Dany, yes. That's what cron does, it automatically executes entries from the crontab list at corresponding times.